# Вывод совпадения в строке PHP

Tags: php, алгоритм

У нас есть две строки "строка" и "сорока".
Нужно вывести самое длинное совпадение символов или массив со всеми совпадениями символов, которые больше одного.
Например в данном случае, должно вывести "рока" - это самое длинное совпадение.
Если строки "Ваптос" и "Запросы", результат будет ["ап", "ос"] - два совпадения по два символа.

```php
$word1 = 'Kangaroo';
$word2 = '/' . 'angar' . '/';
$matches = array();

echo 'Longest common part: ' . preg_match_all($word2, $word1, $matches)."\n";
var_dump( $matches[0] );
```

Результат:

```php
Longest common part: 1
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "angar"
}
```

Есть мысли ?

Comment: есть мысли, что регулярки вряд ли подходят для этой задачи. Смотрели [эти вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) ?

Comment: @Mikhail Abramovich Подскажите, удалось решить задачу?

Comment: У этой задачи даже название есть  - поиск наибольшей общей подстроки. И на вики про неё написано и на хабре хороший разбор алгоритма https://habr.com/ru/post/142825/

Answer (score 0):

Найдет все совпадения в строках.

---

Class:

```
class FindSubStrings {
     /**
      * Properties for hold the strings.
      * 
      * @var string $firstString
      * @var string $secondString
      */
     protected $firstString  = '';
     protected $secondString = '';


     /**
      * Assign the compare strings.
      * 
      * @param string $first
      * @param string $second
      * 
      * @return array
      */
     public function __construct (string $firstStr, string $secondStr) {
         $this->firstString  = str_replace (['"', '/'], ["'", '-'], strtolower ($firstStr));
         $this->secondString = str_replace (['"', '/'], ["'", '-'], strtolower ($secondStr));
     }

      /**
       * Service method for explode the string to different length parts.
       * 
       * @param string $string
       * 
       * @return array
       */
      protected function getStringsParts (string $string): array {
          mb_internal_encoding ("UTF-8");

          $stringParts = [];
          for ($i = 2; $i <= iconv_strlen ($string); $i++) {
              for ($j = 0; $j < iconv_strlen ($string); $j++) {
                  $stringParts[] = mb_substr ($string, $j, $i);
              }
          }

          return $stringParts;
      }

       /**
        * Method, which should return an array with all match which was 
        * found in the strings.
        * 
        * @param void
        * 
        * @return array
        */
       public function getMatches (): array {

           $firstPartsArray    =   $this->getStringsParts ($this->firstString);
           $secondPartsArray   =   $this->getStringsParts ($this->secondString);

           $matches            =   array_unique (array_intersect ($firstPartsArray, $secondPartsArray));

           foreach ($matches as $index1 => $item1) {
                foreach ($matches as $index2 => $item2) {
                    if (iconv_strlen (trim ($item2)) > 1) {
                        if (preg_match ("/($item2)/", $item1) and iconv_strlen ($item2) < iconv_strlen ($item1)) {
                            unset ($matches[$index2]);
                        }
                    } else 
                        unset ($matches[$index2]);
                }
           }

           return $matches;
       }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
/**
 * Choose and sat any strings.
 * 
 * @var string $string1
 * @var string $string2
 */
$string1 = "Football is my favorite game";
$string2 = "footcort is my best place for watch a ball games.";

/**
 * Create instance of FindSubStringsClass.
 * 
 * @var \FindSubStrings $findSubStrings
 * @var array $matches
 */
$findSubStrings =   new FindSubStrings ($string1, $string2);
$matches        =   $findSubStrings->getMatches ();


/**
 * Echo the result.
 */
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($matches);
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [18] => or
    [56] => foot
    [88] => ball 
    [107] =>  game
    [148] =>  is my 
)
```

Comment: Плюсик за идею, но проблемы с русскими словами

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка все решилось при помощи `mb_internal_encoding ("UTF-8");` и использования аналогичной функции `mb_substr ();`

Comment: так же логику с `iconv_strlen` можно упростить (https://pastebin.com/SebG4CBV)

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка совсем отказался от данной проверки

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка Если отформатировать так как вы предлагаете и убрать из конструктора str_replace на двойные ковычки и слеш, то будет не совсем очевиден формат и ограничения строк для сравнения. Слеш или кавычки сломают preg_match(